# Scanner without delimiter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I would like to be able to parse strings like the following: "123456abcd9876az45678". The BNF is like this:

```
number: ? definition of an int ?
word: letter { , letter }
expression: number { , word , number }
```

However the class java.util.scanner doesn't allow me to do the following:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("-123456abcd9876az45678");
System.out.println(s.nextInt());
while (s.hasNext("[a-z]+")) {
    System.out.println(s.next("[a-z]+"));
    System.out.println(s.nextInt());
}
```

Ideally, this should yield:

```
-123456
abcd
987
az
45678
```

I was really hoping that java.util.Scanner would help me, but it looks like I will have to create my own scanner. Is there anything already present in the Java API to help me?

---

The question miss too much information. And therefore all answers are valid to the question but not to my problem.

Comment: I don't know what this code is supposed to do, but I imagine you should have [a-z]* instead of [a-z]

Comment: okay, complete common case is the following "4d8 - 1d4+20" to be parsed as two dice rolls + a constant. There might be more dice rolls, there might be none, there might be spaces or not. Bottom line is I would like to change tokens on the fly without any delimiter. I also don't want to be redirected to the usual dice notation thread in SO since it doesn't help me with all these eval function they are all using. I want to build the tree of the dice expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use no delimiters with the Scanner class AFAIK.  If you wish to ignore delimiters, you'd need to use the methods that does so such as `findInLine()` or `findWithinHorizon()`.  In your case, `findWithinHorizion()` would be appropriate.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("-123456abcd9876az45678");
Pattern num = Pattern.compile("[+-]?\\d+");
Pattern letters = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]+");
System.out.println(s.findWithinHorizon(num, 0));
String str;
while ((str = s.findWithinHorizon(letters, 0)) != null) {
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(s.findWithinHorizon(num, 0));
}
```

Comment: Well, nice idea but I can't build a language with this. I mean that if I search for <number> then again for <number> it will skip all <letter> in order to find the number. I guess I'll have to make my own scanner for this.

Comment: @Frór: It's not much different from the example you gave us except that it works to your specification.  Unless of course there's some other detail that you've left out that you require.

Comment: Yes, there are other requirements I thought were trivial. I'm now thinking about deleting this whole question and recreating a new one with complete overview of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

To use the scanner as a tokenizer, use `findWithinHorizon` with `\G` to scan from the group start (= current position) only.

Example supporting whitespace (as requested in the comments):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
while (true) {
  String letters = scanner.findWithinHorizon("\\G\\s*\\[a-zA-Z]+", 0);
  if (letters != null) {
    System.out.println("letters: " + letters.trim());
  } else {
    String number = scanner.findWithinHorizon("\\G\\s[+-]?[0-9]+", 0);
    if (number != null) {
      System.out.println("number: " + number.trim());
    } else if (scanner.findWithinHorizon("\\G\\s*\\Z", 0) != null) {
      System.out.println("end");
      break;
    } else {
      System.out.println("unrecognized input");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

In real applications, you probably should compile the patterns upfront.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the [Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) classes.  See [this](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/regular-expressions-in-java-1-4-example-1) example.

Comment: Nope regex won't do it. See my comment under the question.

Comment: Your comment does not make it clear to me why the Pattern/Matcher idiom is insufficient.

Comment: Sorry, to be complete, I want something better, something more malleable than the regex. The regex are, in my case, completely overkill draining the flexibility I expect. Thank you anyway !

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long while since the question was asked, the OP is likely not interested in the answer anymore, but it is possible ho have a ***zero-length delimiter***.

```
var s = new Scanner(new ByteArrayInputStream("(2e-3*(4000+5)-.2)".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
s.useDelimiter("(?=[+\\-*/()])|(?<=[+\\-*/()])");
while (s.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print(s.next()+" ");
}
```

prints

```
( 2e - 3 * ( 4000 + 5 ) - .2 )
```

The regex trick is:

- `(?=[+\\-*/()])` means zero-length followed by `+-*/()`, I had to double-escape `-`;
- `(?<=[+\\-*/()])` means zero-length that follows `+-*/()`;
- and between them is `|` "or"

As you see, the floating-point number `2e-3` was split into 3 tokens.

Answer (score -1):

You could set the delimiter to a pattern that can't match anything, e.g.

```
Scanner s = ...
s.useDelimiter("(?!=a)a");
```