# Dice notation (recursive descent parsing implementation): a scanner without delimiter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, dice

I would like to build a recursive descent parsing implementation of the [dice notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice_notation) using the java Scanner if possible. I've previously opened [a question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798902/scanner-without-delimiter) , but it seemed that I had my requirements way too simplified. So I'm presenting here the request in its globality.

I really hope that this is feasible with the class java.util.Scanner, but if needed I will write my own scanner. I would like to avoid this one right now.

```
 expression   =  { whitespace } , [ plusminus ] , roll , { plusminus , ( roll | number , { whitespace } ) } ;
 roll         =  [ number ] , ( "d" | "D" ) , ( number | "%") , [ "-" ( "L" | "H" ) ] , { whitespace } ;
 plusminus    =  ( "+" | "-" ) , { whitespace } ;
 number       =  nonzerodigit , { digit } ;
 digit        =  nonzero digit | "0" ;
 nonzerodigit =  "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9" ;
 whitespace   =  ? Java definition of a whitespace ? ;
```

So in fact, I've tried to write the following code:

```
 Scanner s = new Scanner("1d6");
 if (s.hasNextInt()) {
  s.nextInt();
 } else {
  throw new java.text.ParseException();
 }
```

But obviously it keeps failing.

Also as suggested in the previous question, I've tried the findWithinHorizon methods but it really finds the next pattern and doesn't check from where I am. So I can't "pushback" the string if it is not what I need...

So any suggestion on how I should use java.util.Scanner in this context? Or maybe I have to write my own scanner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use java.util.Scanner. Take a look at the design of [JParsec](https://github.com/jparsec).

Comment: Thanks for the tip about JParsec. I think I will use its design, or if it takes too much time I will use the library itself. However can you explain why I shouldn't use Scanner? Is it because it's not its purpose, because there are better alternatives (like JParsec) or any other reason?

Comment: Your grammar is too different from what this Scanner thing is designed for.

Answer (score 1):

For working with grammars, you should use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). It's a parser generator. From your grammar, you'll be able to generate easily a parser, and use this class to parse your expression.

Comment: Nope, I want it to be done with my hands, so I learn how the parser really works. That's why I explicitly specified the "recursive descent parsing implementation" parenthesis in the title.